# Python remove all punctuation but keeping parentheses and words inside as single item in array

Tags: python, arrays, text

I'm going through a JSON file and creating an array of the individual words as well as other information. So for example I might have WORD [I, like, apples], POS [pron, verb, noun], and LEMMA [I, (to) like, apple]. Currently my code removes all punctuation and adds the individual words to arrays, then I'm using zip() to get everything lined up. However, my current implementation creates an off-by-one error since the LEMMA array ends up being four elements while the others are only three. I've tried removing all punctuation except for parentheses, but then the LEMMA array is six elements total. How can I have "(to)" be added to the same spot in the array as "like"?

My current code is:

```
with open(inputfilename, 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='\r\n') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    #this loop assumes the json is formatted: first-->items-->body-->value
    for line in data:
        #inputLabels are all the user-specified tiers they want in output
        if line['label'] in inputLabels:
            position = inputLabels.index(line['label'])
            items = line['first']['items']
            for item in items:
                tokens = word_tokenize(item['body']['value'])

    for t in tokens:
        t = t.strip('\n')
        if not (t in string.punctuation):
            newLabels[position].append(t)
```

Comment: What is your current implementation? It'd be much more helpful if you could provide some sample inputs with their respective outputs as well.

Comment: Do you manually parse your JSON file? If so, don't. Use the builtin [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module instead to read the whole file into a usable data structure.

Comment: @Robo Mop I have a JSON file from an audio transcription with details about the speech, and my program is for text verticalization (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ioX.png) .The JSON file has different labeled tiers for each type of information (part of speech, lemma, translation, etc). I also edited my question to include my current code.

Comment: Can you share a part of the JSON data?

Comment: Can't share the JSON, unfortunately, but I will edit the question again to include a larger portion of code that shows my basic parsing.

Comment: @smag9467 cold you create a small example file?

Comment: Without an idea of what the JSON looks like it's difficult to give any advice.. But from your description, it sounds like the data is already tokenized, yet you tokenize it again, and that naturally won't always line up with the original tokenization. If you have `word`, `pos`, and `lemma` as synchronized lists, you could skip unwanted elements *after* `zip`ping them so they stay in sync.

Comment: Tried to make a small example file here: https://jsonblob.com/2920976c-cee0-11eb-ac36-aff0288cc5ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is already preprocessed. E.g., if there are three tokens in `SPK_WORD`, there will also be three in `SPK_LEMMA`, `SPK_POS`, etc.

```py
data = list()

with open(inputfilename, 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='\r\n') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for line in data:
        if line['label'] in inputLabels:
            elements = [e['body']['value'] for e in line['first']['items']]
            data.append(elements)
```

This would result in `data` containing synced lists:

```py
# data

[['I', 'like', 'apples'],
 ['pron', 'verb', 'noun'],
 ['I', '(to) like', 'apple']
]
```

From there, you can use `zip` to get all the items and process them in sync, e.g.,

```
for tok in zip(*data):
    print(tok)
```

gives

```
('I', 'pron', 'I')
('like', 'verb', '(to) like')
('apples', 'noun', 'apple')
```